# Access Variable via Bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

I need to access a variable in bytecode.  I have figured out how to do this with local variables (using ILOAD), but I can't seem to get it to work with values that are outside of the method I am working in.  Is there an Opcode that loads a variable inside of a class but outide of a method?

This works when the variable is inside of the method:

```
  if (currentNode.getOpcode() == RETURN)
                    {
                        InsnList toInject = new InsnList();
                        toInject.add(new TypeInsnNode(NEW, "timeTraveler/mechanics/LivingPlaceBlockEvent"));
                        toInject.add(new InsnNode(DUP));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD, 5));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD, 6));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ILOAD, 2));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ILOAD, 3));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ILOAD, 4));
                        toInject.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESPECIAL, "timeTraveler/mechanics/LivingPlaceBlockEvent", "<init>", "(Lnet/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase;Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;III)V"));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ASTORE, 7));
                        toInject.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "net/minecraftforge/common/MinecraftForge", "EVENT_BUS", "Lnet/minecraftforge/event/EventBus;"));
                        toInject.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD, 7));
                        toInject.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "net/minecraftforge/event/EventBus", "post", "(Lnet/minecraftforge/event/Event;)Z"));
                        toInject.add(new InsnNode(POP));
                        m.instructions.insertBefore(currentNode, toInject);
                    }
```

Comment: By "global" you mean "static", right?

Comment: By global I mean a variable declared after the class declaration.

Comment: Would you mind showing a compilable example of a variable declared after a Java class declaration?

Comment: I have added an example of loading a local variable inside the method of question..

Comment: That is not what I mean. I wanted to point out that declaring a variable after a class declaration [will produce a compile-time error](http://ideone.com/CUoww9).

Comment: Inside the class declaration outside of the method.

Comment: You already have an example of that in your code: `FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, `. It accesses the field MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.

Comment: That would be an instance variable or a static variable. If I remember it right, there are different instructions for accessing them. Write a small class that does what you need, then run `javap -c com.mypackage.TestBytecodeClass`, and you will see what Java compiler does.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt has it right. With a new `FieldInsnNode(GETFIELD,` instead.

Comment: You need to read the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/).  Everything you need to know is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined inside a class are called fields. To access them, you use the `getfield` or `getstatic` instructions, depending on whether the field is static or not.

Public static fields are the closest Java has to global variables.